# Weird Angular exception: [$rootScope:inprog] null already in progress

Tags: angularjs

I get a very strange exception with AngularJS 1.5.9

> [$rootScope:inprog] null already in progress

Here is the source code where this exception is thrown:

```
function beginPhase(phase) {
  if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
    throw $rootScopeMinErr('inprog', '{0} already in progress', $rootScope.$$phase);
  }

  $rootScope.$$phase = phase;
}
```

*beginPhase()* is called with "$apply" or "$digest".

My question is:

- How is it possible to enter the "if" while *$rootScope.$$phase* is null?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For the documentation for the error, visit https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

Comment: I get a similar issue reported via our monitoring software - the only way this happens if you pass a string containing 'null' as the function argument. The problem is beginPhase() is only called twice in the entire angular source - and in both cases it takes '$apply' or '$digest'. So while this is a clue, I'm still stumped as to what causes this to occur.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question *$rootScope.$$phase* can be set to ***"null"*** (string) which will result in this error being thrown.

I'm not sure how you were able to capture this message but Sentry reports that for me and I'm getting a ton of those exceptions from just a bunch of users.

So in order to reduce [the spam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGtxM.png) I made a function which will remove the stack from the exception, and will clear the *$rootScope.$$phase* which will hopefully prevent a second occurrence:

```
function exceptionHandler(){
    const error = Error;
    const nullMessage = "[$rootScope:inprog] null already in progress";

    function exception(message){
        if(message.indexOf(nullMessage) === 0){
            const $rootScope = exceptionHandler.$rootScope;
            if($rootScope) $rootScope.$$phase = null;

            const exception = new error(nullMessage);
            exception.stack = "";
            return exception;
        }

        return new error(message);
    }

    Error = exception;
}

exceptionHandler(); // If it's not run AngularJS will use the original Error constructor, the one we're decorating
```

And then in *angular.run* inject *$rootScope* and set it as a property of the function:

```
angular.run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope){
    exceptionHandler.$rootScope = $rootScope;
}]);
```

My assumption was that an extension was setting *$rootScope.$$phase* to *"null"* but after installing the same extensions as one of my users the exception did not occur.

[Star on GistHub](https://gist.github.com/dimitarnestorov/652596709382ef22e736499abcd6f911)

Comment: On which platforms you are getting this exception? We are getting this message from time to time but only in Safari on Mac OS. Can someone confirm this issue? In Safari on Mac OS we also receive "[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress"; from this line of Code `setTimeout(function(){$rootScope.$apply();});`. How is this even possible?

Comment: @kai I stopped getting it. But as much as I remember it was exactly Safari on macOS. I wasn't able to reproduce it on my mac though. Were you able to get it in Safari's console? Cause if you're capable of getting it I would appreciate if you put this gist inside angular.run https://gist.github.com/dimitarnestorov/94bab9f3510b7fced0ea4c5376d59089 and then reporting the stack trace if it throws.